# Equivalent to boost::python py::scope().attr() in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, pybind11

I'm porting some code from `boost::python` to `pybind11`.

I have a class `classA` which I easily wrapped doing:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(module, m) {
   m.doc() = "pybind11 module";
   py::class_<classA>(m, "classA")
      .def(...
      ...
   ;
}
```

And this works perfectly. The issue that I'm facing is that apparently this class used to be called differently in the past, let say `classB`. To maintain backwards compatibility (in the `boost::python` code) the original developer did:

```
py::scope().attr("classB") = py::scope().attr("classA");
```

Is there any equivalent to this on `pybind11`?
Thanks!

Comment: Haven't worked with pybind111 much yet, but from what I can tell, `m` is the module instance. So perhaps `m.attr("classB") = m.attr("classA")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use names: `m.attr("C") = m.attr("B");`, or variable name `class_A`, in this case:

```
class A
{
public:
    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
    }
};
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    py::class_<A> class_A(m, "A");
    class_A.def(py::init<>()).def("hello", &A::hello);

    m.attr("B") = class_A;
    m.attr("C") = m.attr("B");
}
```